# How to fix cannot resolve symbol "MetadataChanges" when implementing firestore recycler adapter?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, cannot-find-symbol

I'm currently trying to implement a Firestore Recycler Adapter into my Android Studio Project but when I when I try to enter the activity with the recyclerView the app crashes. When I use the debugger it crashes when it reaches the .build() method of FireStoreRecyclerOptions. Is it something I'm doing, and if not, is there a workaround?

Here is the code for for the implementation of the RecyclerView:

```
public class SecurityCurrentRequests extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference requestRef = db.collection("Request");
    private Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_security_current_requests);

        setUpRecycler();
    }

    public void setUpRecycler()
    {
        Query query = requestRef.orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Request> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Request>()
                .setQuery(query, Request.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new Adapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

and this is the Adapter Class:

```
public class Adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Request, Adapter.RequestViewHolder> {

    public Adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Request> options){
        super(options);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RequestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //create new instance of the ViewHolder
        // using request_cardview custom layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.request_cardview, parent, false);
        return new RequestViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RequestViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Request requestObject) {


        String firstText = requestObject.getName();
        String secondText = requestObject.getMessage();
        int thirdText = requestObject.getPriority();
        String fourthText = requestObject.getCurrentDate();

        holder.text1.setText(firstText);
        holder.text2.setText(secondText);
        holder.text3.setText(thirdText);
        holder.text4.setText(fourthText);
    }

    public class RequestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView text1, text2, text3, text4;


        RequestViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            text1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            text2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            text3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_priority);
            text4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have the latest versions of all the Firebase libraries you're using.

Comment: As far as I'm aware I have all the up to date Firebase libraries installed, but it's still throwing the error.

 Logcat calls it "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/MetadataChanges;
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions$Builder.setQuery(FirestoreRecyclerOptions.java:86)"